# Android: By rotating ImageView it gets double

Tags: android, xml

I am making a simple chess application and i need to rotate an imageView for the convenience of user, when i use this method my ImageVIew of pawn gets bigger.

```
ImageView pawn;
pawn = (ImageView) findViewById (R.id.pawn);

pawn.setScaleType(ScaleType.MATRIX);
Matrix rotationMatrix = new Matrix();
rotationMatrix.postRotate(180f, pawn.getDrawable().getBounds().width()/2,
     pawn.getDrawable().getBounds().height()/2);
pawn.setImageMatrix(rotationMatrix);
```

I also tried setting my angle to "0f" instead of "180f", i can see only 1/4th of top left image, i think it has something to do with ScaleType.MATRIX or something, i am trapped. Help me!

Answer (score 1):

Actually i am using a new function myRotate(), but their is still a problem that you can use "getResources()" inside main function only as it is not static.

```
public void rotate(ImageView im, int id, int degree){
    Bitmap bMap;
    Matrix matrix;
    //Decode Image using Bitmap factory.
    bMap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), id);
    //Create object of new Matrix.
    matrix = new Matrix();

    //set image rotation value to "degree" degrees in matrix.
    matrix.postRotate(degree);

    //Create bitmap with new values.
    Bitmap bMapRotate = Bitmap.createBitmap(bMap, 0, 0,
            bMap.getWidth(), bMap.getHeight(), matrix, true);

    //put rotated image in ImageView.
    im.setImageBitmap(bMapRotate);
}
```